# Wheel datepickerdialog always shows current date

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using a wheel datepicker dialog everytime I open it shows the current date not the date I set previously.

I am not able to find out where i should make changes.Thanks in advance.

here is the code:

public static void showDatePickerDialog(final Context ctx,
            final TextView view, final EditText preMobileNumberText) {

```
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final Calendar dateandtime = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy", Locale.US);


    DatePickerDailog dp = new DatePickerDailog(ctx, dateandtime,
            new DatePickerDailog.DatePickerListner() {

                @Override
                public void OnDoneButton(Dialog datedialog, Calendar c) {

                    dateandtime.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                    dateandtime.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                    dateandtime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    String selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "MMMM dd yyyy").format(c.getTime());


                    Date date = null;
                    Date cdate = null;
                    try {
                        date = format.parse(selectedDate);
                        long selectedmilliseconds = date.getTime();
                        cdate = format.parse(getCurrentDate());
                        long currentmilliseconds = cdate.getTime();

                        if ((selectedmilliseconds - currentmilliseconds) > 0) {
                            AlertDialogClass
                                    .showAlertNFC(
                                            ctx,
                                            "Please do not select the Future Date for Date of Birth",
                                            "Info");
                        } else {
                            datedialog.dismiss();
                            view.setText(selectedDate);
                        }

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    preMobileNumberText.requestFocus();
                    preMobileNumberText.requestFocusFromTouch();
                }

                @Override
                public void OnCancelButton(Dialog datedialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    datedialog.dismiss();
                    // preMobileNumberText.requestFocus();
                }
            });
    dp.getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    dp.show();
}
```

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116455/setting-the-date-of-a-datepicker-using-the-updatedate-method)

Comment: You can set whatever date or time you want n datepicker, there are methods for it.

Comment: can you tell me the method name

Comment: @Preeti can you please post some code here, so I can know this better

Comment: @Preeti check my answer below, if it is useful to u.

Comment: @pratik I have done that in the code.I am not getting what I have to change can you be more clear please?

Comment: @Preeti http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55195/discussion-about-datepicker join this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, YOUR YEAR VALUE);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, YOUR MONTH VALUE);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, YOUR DAY VALUE);

        dateandtime.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        dateandtime.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        dateandtime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variables into the date you want. Thats it :)

> DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, **year**, **month**, **day**);
>     dialog.show();